# XML Parsing - node.text method removing trailling spaces

Tags: xml-parsing, jscript

I have a big xml file which i'm parsing using jscript. I have used the following code to load the xml

```
var xmlDoc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    xmlDoc.async = false;

    // Load xml data from a file
    xmlDoc.load(this._studyDocPath);
```

Now if i use the following code

```
var text = this.xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(xPath);
text = node.text;
```

the text variable holds the innertext of a perticular tag. But if I have tag like this

```
<Text>ABCD </Text>
```

then the node.text returns me only the value 'ABCD' i.e. it automatically trims the space. But I dont need to trim any trailling spaces. I need the text as it is. How can I achieve that?

Looking forward to your response

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use node.firstChild.nodeValue with a null check on node.firstChild